# Possibility to optimize mysql query?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have mysql query, execution time is about 0.15 sec, it update every day about 20000 lines, so it's take about 1 hour or more.

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta a
JOIN wp_postmeta b  ON a.post_id = b.post_id
AND b.meta_key = '_sku'
AND b.meta_value LIKE '$sku'
SET a.meta_value = CASE a.meta_key
WHEN '_price' THEN '$retail'
WHEN '_sale_price' THEN '$retail'
WHEN '_regular_price' THEN '$retail'
WHEN '_stock' THEN '$stock'
ELSE a.meta_value
END;
```

Is there any possibility to increase speed of the query?

Comment: I don't know that there is anything there that's terribly slow. Are you sure that all the fields that you are checking are indexed? Or that you are on a big enough box?

Comment: why the self join?Use a WHERE clause

Comment: I think you can change this line `AND b.meta_value LIKE '$sku'` to `AND b.meta_value = '$sku'`. Maybe this can bring another millisecond or so. If that doesn't help, you could try to make three queries. The first to get the post_id, the second to update all rows where the meta_value is $retail and the third to update all rows with the meta_value $stock. Sometimes it is faster to do more but simpler queries.

Comment: Mihai, could you explain?

Comment: Florian, now is about 0.07 - 0.09, thank you, better. But it's possbile more better? :)

Comment: Yes, i also thinked about this, but idea do it without php

Comment: But you are already using PHP aren't you? I think, this could really make a difference!

Comment: Sorry, explain - i use export to csv only on showing in php. The table what i update on another server, and i do update by ssh

Comment: Ok, sorry. I just saw you using WordPress and your query has variables in it that looked like PHP syntax. Never mind.